# Expo build fails due to import resolution error

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

getting resolution error with typescript

src/constants/Config.ts

```
export const Config = {
  auth0: {
    client_id: 'xxxx',
    connection: 'xxxx',
    url: 'https://xxxx.eu.auth0.com',
  },
};
```

```
import {Config} from '@src/constants/Config';
```

using expo on react-native, getting faild to build script

```
Unable to resolve "@src/constants/Config" from "src/containers/layouts/auth/signUp2/signUp2.component.tsx"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

tried building with tsc, the build is fine, but running expo start yeilds that error

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/tsc-out",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2016"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@kitten/*": ["./node_modules/react-native-ui-kitten/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

babel

```
const path = require('path');
const Config = require('./config');

// FIXME: Resolve `transform[stderr]: Could not resolve` command-line warnings.
// FIXME: Reproducible when starting with clearing cache (npm start -- -c)
//
// TODO: Framework path aliasing even not needed here. Replace?
// TODO: Replace nested package.json-s with aliases

const moduleResolverConfig = {
  root: path.resolve('./'),
  alias: {
    '@kitten/theme': path.resolve(Config.KITTEN_PATH, 'theme'),
    '@kitten/ui': path.resolve(Config.KITTEN_PATH, 'ui'),
    '@eva-design/eva': path.resolve(Config.MAPPING_PATH),
    '@eva-design/processor': path.resolve(Config.PROCESSOR_PATH),
  },
};

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = [
    'babel-preset-expo',
  ];

  const plugins = [
    ['module-resolver', moduleResolverConfig],
  ];

  return { presets, plugins };
};
```

Comment: Try to use relative path

Comment: that made it work, but what's the point of having aliases if they do not work!

Comment: you can do it with babel config: https://github.com/janaagaard75/expo-and-typescript/issues/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working is setting both babel config and tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

I see Kitten Tricks application config files here. The point of having aliases is only to have a development environment for this application, as we use it sometimes to review react-native-ui-kitten changes. If you use it only in production mode, you're able to remove `dev.env.js` in `./config` folder.